# How to make data sorted when export to excel

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, excel, jsp

I had created a tablecolumn and using build in sort

```
<ui:tableColumn binding="#{tms$gate$GatePassList.tableColumn2}" headerText="Issuer" id="tableColumn2" sort = "userupdateid">
```

And i also have the button function call "Export to excel"

But the problem i meet is when i display data onto table, example: B C A. After that i sort it to A B C. but i export to excel, it is still B C A.

is it because the sorting is only on the table, and the export to excel take data from database?

Comment: what's this `<ui:tableColumn>` tag, are you using your own tag library or a specific third party tag library?

Comment: What command is executed when you press that button?

Comment: which button u mean? "Export to excel" is generate all the data in the table to excel file.